# why raise(3) core dump file no stack frame symble

Tags: stack, coredump, raise

**ENV:** linux kernel 3.4, uclibc 0.9.33

**Description:** I use raise(3) and kill(3) send *SIGSEGV* to process and create a core dump file.I found 2 file ***bt*** is difference.

**raise(3):**

```
void fun2(void)
{
    raise(SIGSEGV);
}

void fun1(void)
{
    fun2();
}

int main(void)
{
    fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

**core dump file stack frame:**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xc6f7f2d4 in ?? ()
#1  0xc6f7f2a0 in ?? ()
#2  0xc6f7f2a0 in ?? ()
```

**kill(3):**

```
void fun2(void)
{
    kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);
}

void fun1(void)
{
    fun2();
}

int main(void)
{
    fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

**core dump file stack frame:**

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xc6f043f0 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000852c in fun2 () at test.c:20
#2  0x0000853c in fun1 () at test.c:25
#3  0x0000854c in main () at test.c:30
```

**question:**

1. why raise(3) frame addr so big, what dose the number mean?
2. why raise(3) have not symble in stack frame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I set sysroot when load core dump file ,then raise and kill bt become same.**